# Preventing a specific application from accessing a folder, in user space

Tags: permissions, restricted-access

I have an app which recursively scans through huge directories, which is even slower because those are on NFS. It seems that I cannot configure the app in a way to stop this. However, I still want to use the app, and the app in fact should not need to access those directories at all.

[Related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258257/preventing-a-specific-application-from-accessing-a-folder) but the solution here is to use AppArmor.

As far as I know, AppArmor requires root access. However, I'm searching for a solution which I can do without root access. Also, AppArmor looks way too complex for what I want.

I probably could inject some small library via `LD_PRELOAD` to wrap any `opendir` calls. This would solve it.

But something like this must exist already, or not?

Comment: Sandboxing is what restricts access of an app.

Comment: `firejail` might do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found [ld-preload-open](https://github.com/fritzw/ld-preload-open) where I can set mappings. I just map all paths which I want to block to `/dev/null`. This works perfectly as intended.

Do debug what files/paths are actually accessed by the app, I simply do:

```
strace -e trace=file -f my-app
```