# What is reason for apparmor="DENIED" operation="open"

Tags: apparmor

```
Jan 26 13:25:27 nanak-P570WM kernel: [ 3184.247986] type=1400 audit(1390703127.047:85): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=2911 profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/home/jagat/.config/dconf/user" pid=7426 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1001 ouid=0
```

Why above message in kern.log and how to fix it.

Comment: Does my answer answer your question or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 3):

The [mission-control-5](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/mission-control-5.8.html) process tried to open and read the `/home/jagat/.config/dconf/user` file and [Apparmor](https://askubuntu.com/q/236381/44179) stopped it.

I'm not sure *why* mission-control wanted to read that file, but unless you have been tinkering with apparmor or think you are experiencing problems because of this, you shouldn't need to take any actions.