# Ubuntu security: "antivirus" in official statement?

Tags: 13.10, security, documentation, antivirus

I use current (and vanilla) Ubuntu in a work environment. (It is, in the main, a Windows-orientated outfit.) A question has come up about antivirus, and I see this on the [official Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/business):

> The default settings prioritise security, and Ubuntu comes with a firewall, antivirus software and file and disk encryption tools.

However, poking around dash, etc., I can't find any sign of "antivirus software" on my machine. **What does this statement refer to?**

FWIW, I have read (I think) most of the "antivirus" Q&A's on AskUbuntu, but haven't found this one dealt with. (If I've missed it, please point me in the right direction. Thanks!)

Comment: This appears to be incorrect, I've filed a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website-content/+bug/1305065

Answer (score 1):

I think it's referring to `apparmor` which is indeed installed by default (not sure if it goes under the antivirus category though).

See [What is apparmor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236381/what-is-apparmor) for further details about the kind of protections it provides.

Comment: Thanks for this - hard to see that it's on my system. Running `apparmor` from terminal gets a `command not found` response. The info at the (helpful) link suggests that there should be some means of interacting with the program. Grateful for this info, though.

Comment: It's not really an antivirus, so feel free to accept my answer or not ;-). But you can at least give your up-vote. Thanks.

Comment: Yep. :) Just had other things to do. Will be interesting to see if this gets any other input. Thanks for yours!