# LibreOffice AppArmor messages issue

Tags: libreoffice, apparmor

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.1 LTS, installed from the scratch, with a DVD made with the ISO image directly from the website.

I installed LibreOffice 6.0.6.2, also from the correspondent official website.

Everything works fine (texts, images, presentations, databases, spreadsheets, etc), but...

There is always a lot of AppArmor messages in the screen when we open, save and/or close a LibreOffice file!

Just see the sample screen capture!

[image: LibreOffice AppArmor messages issue]

How can we avoid all those messages? How can we fix this?

Comment: Look for clues in the kern.log with `tail -n 20 /var/log/kern.log`

Comment: There is nothing related with LibreOffice into that register. I just found items related with UFW and my local Internet network device.

Answer (score 1):

These logs come from **apparmor**.

I am new to this software, but basically appparmor has a rule (i.e. setting) for LibreOffice defining a *complaint mode*. 
When libreoffice is trying to write certain files a warning is logged.

You can stop this logs by removing the app-armor rule for libreoffice.

Refer for instance to these links for more details:

- [What is apparmor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236381/what-is-apparmor)
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer (needs further work):

From `dmesg`:

```
[368277.340304] audit: type=1400 audit(1597124108.053:1237): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="file_lock" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name=...hex... pid=791629 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="wk" denied_mask="wk" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[368277.456475] audit: type=1400 audit(1597124108.169:1238): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="rename_src" profile="libreoffice-soffice" name=...hex... pid=791629 comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="wrd" denied_mask="wrd" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

And matching apparmor rules:

```
$ grep -E "wk|wrd" /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.libreoffice.program.soffice.bin
  owner @{libo_user_dirs}/**.@{libreoffice_ext} rwk,  #Open files rw with the right exts
  owner @{libo_user_dirs}/{,**/}lu??????????{,?}.tmp rwk, #Temporary file used when saving
  owner @{HOME}/.config/libreoffice{,dev}/** rwk,
  owner @{HOME}/.config/soffice.binrc.lock rwk,
  owner @{HOME}/.config/QtProject.conf.lock rwk,
  owner @{HOME}/.local/share/RecentDocuments/*.lock rwk,
  owner @{HOME}/.config/kdeglobals.lock rwk,
```

Must have something to do with these. Removing the rules is possible (the 'partial answer'), but likely not the best answer, hence 'partial'. Please comment with better suggestions and I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since I upgraded my system to the last Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS version, and Libre Office has been upgraded to the last 6.4.6 version, I don't have more AppArmor messages. So... I guess it is solved.